# How to see if an object is more approximately equal

Tags: java, generics, comparable, approximate

I have the method:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> T moreApproxEqual(T object, T less, T greater) {
    //TODO: return less or greater, depending on which is closer to object
    return null;
}
```

I have a list of T and from that I found the variables "less" and "greater" to be the closest two values in the list to the variable "object". Is there any way I can tell if one of the two objects is closer to "object" without any more information on the objects?

Comment: Since those are `Comparable` you can use `compareTo`...

Comment: `compareTo` doesn't promise anything about the "closeness" of the values, though, last i checked. You can't rely on the return value to be bigger if the two objects are more dissimilar.

Comment: @cHao While this is true, if you are creating the classes yourself, you could technically have your `compareTo()` method return a distance (where negative => less than and positive => greater than). You should probably just create a `distance()` method for this though instead...

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll: A `distance()` method would indeed be far more appropriate.  No good reason to dual-purpose `compareTo()` like that, as it would add behavior you can't rely on from any other implementation.

Answer (score 5):

No.  You can tell that `object` is between `less` and `greater`, but in general, `Comparable` gives you no information about "distance" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: This is correct. You can not tell which one is closer if you have only less or more information.